# Pass array of template size to function using an initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

I have a templated function, which takes an `std::array` of arbitrary size as an argument. It looks roughly like this:

```
template <size_t n>
void foo(const std::array<int, n>& numbers) {
    for (const auto & number: numbers) {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

I can call it e.g. like so:

```
std::array<int, 2> ints = {4, 5};
foo(ints);
```

and everything is fine.

Unfortunately I cannot call the function directly using an initializer list. This code:

```
foo({4, 5});
```

gives me the following error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'foo'
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'n'
```

Is there a way to make my function work using an initializer list or something similar?

Comment: `void foo(std::initializer_list<int> numbers)` ?

Comment: Apart from that `foo<2>({4, 5});` would also work. Yes, ugly, but it could be worse.

Comment: @Jarod42 then I could not pass already existing arrays anymore, could I?

Comment: @ypnos ah yes this works...thank you. But why doesn't this work without specializing the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{/*..*/}`has no type and so cannot be deduced in template function except for `std::initializer_list<T>` and for C-arrays `T (&a)[N]`.

So you have to

- add overload to handle `std::initializer_list<int>` or C-array.

  ```
  // span (C++20) has constructor from std::array :)
  void foo(const std::span<int>& numbers) {
      for (const auto & number: numbers) {
          // ... do stuff ...
      }
  }

  void foo(std::initializer_list<int> numbers) {
      foo(std::span{numbers.begin(), numbers.size()});
  }
  ```
- or provide non deduced template parameter: `foo<2>({4, 5});`
- or provide type to `{}` (easier with CTAD of C++17): `foo(std::array{4, 5});`

Comment: `std::span` is awesome but note it is introduced with C++20 (doesn't take away from the answer, just in case anyone wants to try the code example).

Comment: @ypnos: Indeed, I used `span` to avoid to duplicate code. In previous standard, we might use version taking 2 iterators or re-implementing `span`.